# Como poner coordenadas en Google Maps desde una variable

Tags: android-studio, google-maps

.
Hola buenos días, a ver si me podéis sacar de este atasco.

Como puedo pasar las coordenadas al Google Maps almacenadas en una variable.

De la forma que lo estoy utilizando me está dando error porque no sé cómo poner las coordenadas en el Google Maps para que trace la ruta.

**Datos.java** (Clase Frangment)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.bt_s_vi:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),GPS.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitud","38.406659");
            intent.putExtra("longitud","-0.777022");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.bt_s_vi2:
               …
               …
               …
         break;
}
}
```

**GPS.java** (Clase FragmentActivity)

```
TextView tvDatos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String d1 = extras.getString("latitud");
    String d2 = extras.getString("longitud");
    tvDatos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDatos);
    tvDatos.setText(d1+","+d2);

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

   Mapa(googleMap);

}

public void Mapa (GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;

    final LatLng Destino = new LatLng(tvDatos );
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Destino).title("Destino").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Destino));

}
```

Gracias.

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: no llego a utilizar el emulador porque antes ya me muestra un error, estoy probando y cambiando el código pero me sigue mostrando un mensaje de error, voy a editar el primer post con el nuevo código, y te pongo aqui el mensaje que muestra http://funkyimg.com/i/2R95L.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas pasando un String cuando LatLng espera Double:

```
    String[] parts = datosobtenidos.split(",");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
    double lon = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
    LatLng Destino = new LatLng( lat,lon);
```

Comment: perdona Igmer no vi tu comentario, he probado a dejar el código como estaba al principio para probar el el código que has puesto, pero hay que poner en final `LatLng Destino = new LatLng(` **xxxx** `);` porque me tira un error.

Comment: funciona con final?

Comment: si, la prueba que he realizado a funcionado, voy a probar un par de veces con otras coordenadas, pero solo una cosa que no se si se puede configurar, pensaba que no hacia falta, pero cuando muestra el market de destino, hay que volver a pulsar sobre ese market, hay posibilidad de que eso no pase, quiero decir que cuando recoja las coordenadas muestre el mapa con la ruta trazada.

Answer (score 2):

Al recibir los valores de latitud y longitud en el bundle, puedes convertirlos de String a Double y usarlos para determinar :

```
 LatLng Destino = new LatLng(latitud, longitud);
```

Se realizaría de esta forma:

```
TextView tvDatos;
private Double latitud;
private Double longitud;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    //String d1 = extras.getString("latitud");
    //String d2 = extras.getString("longitud");
    latitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("latitud"));
    longitud = Double.parseDouble(extras.getString("longitud"));

    tvDatos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDatos);
    tvDatos.setText(String.valueOf(latitud)+","+String.valueOf(latitud));

}
```

al obtener los datos de `latitud`, `longitud` puedes usarlos para crear la posición del marcador.

```
public void Mapa (GoogleMap googleMap){
    mMap = googleMap;

    final LatLng Destino = new LatLng(latitud, longitud); //***
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Destino).title("Destino").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Destino));

}
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, cambié el código por el primero que puse, que igual tu no llegaste a ver, pero lo he vuelto a cambiar para probar con lo que me dices, y también me funciona. **Lo que pregunto es** si se puede pasar directamente al mapa para que muestre la ruta trazada, en lugar de tener que pulsar primero en el market ?

Comment: esta respuesta deberia ser marcada como correcta, es la manera correcta de realizarlo